# Burcam 506532ss booster pump pressure too high

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, pump

New user here.  Hope someone can help.  I just installed a Burcam 506532ss Water Pressure Boost Pump

[image]

to help with my municipal water pressure.

Example:  [Burcam 506532ss Water Pressure Boost Pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003AJDNRU) (Amazon.com)

It is in a closed system with a check valve to stop back flow.  We are at the end of the water line and the pressure coming in is very low 20-22 psi max.  I have gauges installed to measure before and after the pump.  The pump runs on demand and shuts off after the demand stops.

The problem is that it runs the pressure up to 100-120 psi and once the water heater kicks in it goes even higher due to thermal expansion.

I know this is not safe and from the specs on the pump it should not go that high.

Can anyone tell me what could be happening?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention an expansion tank installed after the pump that would allow the pressure device time to respond to a shut off of the flow or demand. The expansion tank would also absorb the thermally expanded water.

Comment: I do not have an expansion tank, but never had one prior to this pump.  Also the pump is a replacement for the same exact model I had before.